# Use query using Col number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

```
=QUERY(CE4:CL22,"SELECT AI, sum(AJ), sum(AK), SUM(AL), SUM(AM), SUM(AO) group by AI")
```

Can I make a formula like that in google sheet but use the Column number instead the column name for example:

```
=QUERY(CA4:CL22,"SELECT Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3), SUM(Col4), SUM(Col5), SUM(Col6) group by Col1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. Just use array notation `{...}` like-

```
=QUERY({CA4:CL22},"SELECT Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3), SUM(Col4), SUM(Col5), SUM(Col6) group by Col1")
```